# RGeo convex hull of list of points

Tags: ruby, rgeo

RGeo has convex hull method available, but no documentation at all in this matter.

Given set of Points, how to I find their convex hull?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. Turns out there is a geometry type called "[MultiPoint](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/dazuma/rgeo/RGeo/Feature/MultiPoint)" that works for this. I made a simple example to test it out and it appears to work well.

```
f = RGeo::Geos.factory(:srid => 3361, :buffer_resolution => 8) #my typical local rectilinear projection factory with my default settings.
coords = [[1,1], [2,2], [1,3]]
points = []
coords.each {|x,y| points << f.point(x,y)}
```

[image: points]

```
f.multi_point(points).convex_hull
```

[image: looks good to me]

Comment: I tried your solution but getting **NoMethodError: undefined method `factory' for #<RGeo::Geos::CAPIFactory:0x4a9bc54 srid=4326 bufres=1 flags=8>** error

Comment: Looks like you're calling the factory method on a factory

Comment: fix that issue, need to install `libgeos` package

Comment: To really illustrate the "convex hull" behaviour, this answer should show adding another point which lies within the area of the triangle formed by the other three points. As expected, the `convex_hull` method returns a polygon still with only the outside three points.

Comment: (by the way, I edited the answer to fix the factory method on factory)

Comment: This appears to work for a `RGeo::Geos.factory` but not for a `RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory`. You can use a `RGeo::Geos.factory` and then convert to the other type but the conversion might create an invalid polygon.